# Best approximation of sum of unit vectors by a smaller subset

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

Let $v_1,\ldots,v_N$ be linear independent unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and denote their scaled sum by $s_N = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N v_k.$ I would like to find a small subset of size $n$ among those vectors such that their scaled sum approximates $s_N$ well. In other words find

$$ J = \underset{J\in\mathscr{J}}{\operatorname{argmin}} \bigg\lVert s_N - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n v_{J_k}\bigg\rVert$$

where $J$ runs over the set $\mathscr{J}$ of all subsets of $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ with size $n$ and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the euclidean norm.

The set of vectors can be considered an iid sample drawn uniformly from the sphere. And, of course, in my case $N$ and $n$ are too large ($N$ will be of the order of 10'000 or 100'000 and $n$ maybe one or two magnitudes smaller) to just try all subsets. So  I am looking for something more clever.

### My approach so far

I tried

- *Repeated random subsampling*, i.e. drawing many, many subsets of size $n$ in an iid fashion, calculating the approximation for each instance and retaining the best.
- *Greedy* approach, starting with a single vector, and then increasing the set in steps every time by a single vector. The vector is that single vector which gives the best approximation for the enlarged set.

### Questions

- Is this a known problem with a proper name?
- Is it hard (as in *NP-hard* for example) or are clever solutions known?
- Are there better heuristic approaches?
- Are there theoretic results/performance guarantees for the two heuristics I used?

**Note**: I edited the question to include scaling. Some of the answers/comments refer to the older version where vectors were not scaled.

Comment: Might not be terribly helpful, but note that the problem could be reformulated as minimizing $\|Ax - s_N\|$, where $A$ is the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_N$ and $x$ is taken from the set of vectors whose entries are either $0$ or $1$ and with $1$-norm at most $n$.  I suspect that if $\|\cdot\|$ is replaced with the $1$-norm, then this can be framed as an [integer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) problem.

Comment: Interestingly, each sum can be thought of as a corner of a the parallelpiped generated by the vectors.

Comment: If the $v_i$ are close to being orthogonal (i.e. $A$ satisfies the [restricted isometry property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_isometry_property)), then I suspect that putting $1$s in for the largest $n$ entries of the least-squares solutions to $Ax = s_N$ should be a good heuristic.

Comment: They should be "close to orthogonal" due to symmetry and central limit theorem. I would need to dig a bit deeper into the restricted isometry property to say something definite. But I do not understand the remark about the "largest $n$ entries". The solution to $Ax = s_N$ is straightforward: it is $x=(1,\ldots,1)$ by definition. So what are "the largest $n$ entries"?

Comment: Never mind! I didn't understand that $s_N$ is necessarily the sum of *all* $v_i$. So that said, it's clear that the least squares solution doesn't give you any information.

Comment: It might be useful to consider the relaxation where we find the minimum of $\|s_N - Ax\|$ subject to the constraint that $\|x\| \leq \sqrt{n}$. I suspect that this has an analytic solution in terms of the SVD of $A$. We would then take **this** solution and consider the largest $n$ entries, or apply some similar trick.

Comment: This paper might help: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @BenGrossmann, you can use integer linear programming to minimize the 1-norm.  Explicitly, let binary decision variable $x_j$ indicate whether $j \in J$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^N (z_i^+ + z_i^-)$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
(s_N)_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^N (v_j)_i x_j &= z_i^+ - z_i^- &&\text{for $i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$} \\
\sum_{j=1}^n x_j &= n \\
z_i^+ &\ge 0 &&\text{for $i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$}\\
z_i^- &\ge 0 &&\text{for $i \in \{1,\dots,N\}$}
\end{align}

This might provide a good approximation for your 2-norm objective or a good starting solution for an improvement heuristic.

---

For the 2-norm, the problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^N \left((s_N)_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^N (v_j)_i x_j\right)^2$ subject to linear constraint
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = n \tag1
$$

Because $x_i$ is binary, we have $x_i^2 = x_i$.  For $i < j$, you can linearize each product $x_i x_j$ as described [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables).

You can also strengthen the formulation by multiplying both sides of the cardinality constraint $(1)$ by $x_i$, yielding:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} x_j x_i + x_i^2 + \sum_{j=i+1}^n x_i x_j = n x_i$$
And then linearize this quadratic constraint by using the products from the objective linearization:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} y_{j,i} + \sum_{j=i+1}^n y_{i,j} = (n - 1) x_i$$

---

Given a feasible solution, a simple improvement heuristic for either norm is to replace one vector in $J$ with one vector not in $J$ if it improves the objective value.

Comment: I do not have any experience with integer linear programming. But from my experience with plain vanilla linear programming I'd say these direct attack methods do not work since the number of variables (~100K) is too large. And the integer constraint would not simplify the problem wouldn'it?

Comment: But I think your idea of using some approximate solution as clever starting point for a greedy improvement sounds interesting.

Comment: Ah, and why do you suggest to minimize the 1-norm instead of the 2-norm?

Comment: 100K variables is not large for commercial LP solvers.  Right, enforcing integrality makes things harder.  The 1-norm is more easily linearized than 2-norm.

Comment: If the ILP problem is too large to solve directly, a heuristic approach is to sample a random subset, solve the problem for that subset, and repeat as desired,

Comment: you can simply switch to 2-norm optimization by using mixed integer second order cone optimization, I doubt that is any slower than linear optimization for this problem

Comment: @LinAlg, the 2-norm can also be linearized because all variables are binary.

Comment: you are right, but I have yet to see an example where linearizing the 2-norm is beneficial compared to solving a mixed integer SOCO problem

Comment: @LinAlg I assume "mixed integer SOCO" = "Mixed integer quadratic programming" or MIQP. Correct? 

According to the CRAN view on optimisation MIQP is only covered by commercial solvers. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RobPratt: What would I need to do to "linearize" L2 optimisation?

Comment: I just updated my answer to describe the 2-norm linearization.

Comment: @gg SOCO is second order cone optimization, which is slightly more general than MIQO. Yes, you need a commercial solver (CPLEX/Gurobi/MOSEK, free academic license available), but the performance of free solvers for mixed integer (linear) optimization is so awful that you need a commercial solver regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ denote the matrix whose columns are $v_1,\dots,v_N$. Then your problem is that of minimizing $\|s_N - Ax\|$ subject to the constraint that $x$ has $0,1$ entries and $\|x\| \leq \sqrt{n}$.

Removing the constraint that $x$ has $0,1$ entries leaves us with a much easier problem to deal with. I suspect that its solution will yield a useful heuristic.

If $A = U \Sigma V^T$ is an SVD and we make the substitutions $b = U^Ts_N$ and $y = V^Tx$, we are left with the simplified problem
$$
\min \|\Sigma y - b\| \quad \text{s.t. } \quad \|y\| \leq \sqrt{n}.
$$
This is easily solved with Lagrange multipliers. The squared objective and constraint functions have the forms
$$
f(y) = \|\Sigma y - b\|^2 \implies \nabla f = 2 [\Sigma^2 y - \Sigma b]
\\g(y) = \|y\|^2 \implies \nabla g = 2y
$$
So, we have
$$
\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g \implies \Sigma^2 y - \Sigma b = \lambda y \implies (\Sigma^2 - I)y = \lambda \Sigma b \implies y = \lambda(\Sigma^2 - I)^{-1}\Sigma b.
$$
Note: this assumes that $A$ does not have $1$ as a singular value, which occurs with probability $1$. Plugging into the constraint yields
$$
\|\lambda(\Sigma^2 - I)^{-1}\Sigma b\|^2 = n \implies \lambda = \pm \sqrt{\frac{n}{\|(\Sigma^2 - I)^{-1}\Sigma b\|^2}},
$$
which is simply to say that this solution for $y$ should be normalized to the radius-$\sqrt{n}$ sphere.

I'm not sure if this can be written in terms that remove the SVD. For what it's worth, though, we have
$$
(\Sigma^2 - I)^{-1}\Sigma = V^T[(A^TA - I)^{-1}\sqrt{A^TA}]V.
$$

Comment: Thanks, very interesting idea. But you did not explain the useful heuristic. Judging from your previous comments we should retain the $n$ vectors in $A$ which have largest coefficients in $x=Vy$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that was what I was thinking

Comment: Well, I gave it a shot. It is a good heuristic but greedy beats it. I tried N=1000, n=100 and measured the relative error $ \frac{\lVert A\hat{x} - s_N \rVert}{\lVert s_N \rVert}$ (i.e. smaller is better).

The graph in the attached link shows the CDFs of 100 independent replications. For comparison "rnd" is a random pick of 100. 

graph is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ebP2.jpg

Comment: Ah, that's a shame.

Comment: Yeah, I agree! But that is applied maths.Gromov once said: "Biology is much harder than math! Because a good idea in math is likely true. In biology not!". I think applied math shares this issue.

Comment: That said: What about the same idea but with L1 regularization?

Comment: @gg Sorry I'm just responding now. L1 regularization makes sense, especially since the L1 norm is often sparsity-inducing. That said, I don't know enough to say anything helpful about its implementation or success.